# ESB Mule Client staring with xml-properties fails

Tags: esb, mule

I use Mule 3.x

I have a code that tests MuleClient connectivity.

This test is ok and works proper way:

```
public void testHello() throws Exception
    {
        MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
        MuleMessage result = client.send("http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello", "some data", null);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertNull(result.getExceptionPayload());
        assertFalse(result.getPayload() instanceof NullPayload);

        //TODO Assert the correct data has been received
        assertEquals("hello", result.getPayloadAsString());
    }
```

But this tes is not ok - it fail with an connection exceptions:

```
public void testHello_with_Spring() throws Exception {

    MuleClient client = new MuleClient("mule-config-test.xml");
    client.getMuleContext().start();

    //it fails here
    MuleMessage result = client.send("http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello", "some data", null);
    assertNotNull(result);

    assertNull(result.getExceptionPayload());
    assertFalse(result.getPayload() instanceof NullPayload);

    //TODO Assert the correct data has been received
    assertEquals("hello", result.getPayloadAsString());
}
```

The 'mule-config-test.xml' is  used in both tests, the path for this file is ok, i checked.

This is error message I have in the end:

> Exception stack is:
>   1. Address already in use (java.net.BindException)   java.net.PlainSocketImpl:-2 (null)
>   2. Failed to bind to uri "http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello" (org.mule.transport.ConnectException)
>   org.mule.transport.tcp.TcpMessageReceiver:81
>   (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/ConnectException.html)
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.net.BindException: Address already in
>   use   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
>       + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>
> ---
>
> [10-05 16:33:37] ERROR HttpConnector [main]:
>   org.mule.transport.ConnectException: Failed to bind to uri
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello" [10-05 16:33:37] ERROR ConnectNotifier
>   [main]: Failed to connect/reconnect: HttpConnector {
>   name=connector.http.mule.default   lifecycle=stop   this=7578a7d9
>   numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
>   createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true   connected=false
>   supportedProtocols=[http]   serviceOverrides= } . Root Exception
>   was: Address already in use. Type: class java.net.BindException [10-05
>   16:33:37] ERROR DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy [main]: Failed to bind
>   to uri "http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello"
>
> org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Cannot process event as
>   "connector.http.mule.default" is stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in what you're not showing: `testHello_with_Spring()` is probably executing while Mule is already running. The second Mule you're starting in it then port-conflicts with the other one.

Are `testHello()` and `testHello_with_Spring()` in the same test suite? If yes, seeing that `testHello()` relies on an already running Mule, I'd say that would be the cause of port conflict for `testHello_with_Spring()`.

Comment: Yes, this is related to. Actually I have been running only second method. But there is a line: HelloTestCase extends FunctionalTestCase which is responsible for starting the mule server by itself in the beginning of all tests.